# Rails 3.1 generator, no Rails::Generators::Base

Tags: templates, ruby-on-rails-3.1, generator

I'm using Rails 3.1 to re-write a generator.

The Rails guide says to start with the following example:

```
class InitializerGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
  def create_initializer_file
    create_file "config/initializers/initializer.rb", "# Add initialization content here"
  end
end
```

However, the neither the Rails::Generators nor Rails::Generator namespace seem to be defined.

Is there a guide for Rails 3.1 generators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

require 'rails/generators'